# How to customize a select element through CSS to achieve this dark style?

Tags: html, css

How can I create a select element like the below image?

[image]

My code is

```
<select>
    <option>-- Select City --</optoin>
    <option>Delhi</option>
    <option>Gurgaon</option>
</select>
```

This is available in jQuery, but I want to use pure CSS.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. You want an image to be behind each of the select options?

Comment: @Miles yes i want to background images in select options if is possible in pure css ...?

Comment: Discourage use of dropkick due to the widths issue: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769888/how-to-individually-target-multiple-dropdowns-in-css-for-dropkick-plug-in

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a CSS-powered select menu; you can customize it as you need to:

```css
label.custom-select {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}

.custom-select select {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 3px 3px 5px;
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    outline:none; /* remove focus ring from Webkit */
    line-height: 1.2;
    background: #000;
    color:white;
    border:0;
}

/* Select arrow styling */
.custom-select:after {
    content: "▼";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 60%;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 7px;
    background: #000;
    color: white;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.no-pointer-events .custom-select:after {
    content: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="custom-select">
    <select>
        <option>Sushi</option>
        <option>Blue cheese with crackers</option>
        <option>Steak</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/426wLqmp/)

Answer (score 4):

Using the `pointer-events:none;` it will let you click through the arrow and will activate the select field, So the CSS would look like this for that element.

```css
.custom-select:after {
    content: "▼";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 60%;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 7px;
    background: #000;
    color: white;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
option{
  background-image:url(image.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to customise the select as you see it in your screenshot without Javascript.

You can see in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2XHm7/) that you can customise colors, padding and borders, but not the button itself.

Answer (score -1):

Even though you added a background image to the selectbox, you can not hide that handler on right hand side. I would recommend to use this : 
http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/

You just have to modify the CSS a bit to suit your need.