# Remove border radius from Select tag in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This seems like a trivial problem, but I can't figure it out.

On Bootstraps own website they have the Select example.

[image: bootstrap select]

Looking at the code it looks like there's a border-radius of 4 on that select element. 
[image]

My hope would be that changing that border-radius to 0 would then remove the border-radius from the select element, however, that's not the case - as seen in the picture below.

[image]

I've explored all the CSS that is changing that select element but none of it seems to remove the border radius.

Comment: Changing the border radius on the `.form-control` class works fine for me. http://www.bootply.com/Q7goAsFc0B

Comment: Even in your example there's rounded corners on that select element...?

Comment: Turns out it's a issue with Chrome. Opening up your bootply in firefox it's not rounded. Weird.

Comment: Works for me in both Chrome and FF.

Comment: Then it's specific to my machine. Not sure what's going on. Thanks for the help.

Comment: for me it doesn't work in chrome but works fine in firefox

Comment: @TylerMcGinnis Unrelated, but how did you change your dev tools color scheme? I love it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css)

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Here is a version that works in all modern browsers. The key is using `appearance:none` which removes the default formatting. Since all of the formatting is gone, you have to add back in the arrow that visually differentiates the select from the input. *Note: [`appearance` is not supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance#Browser_compatibility).*

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gs2q1c7p/

```css
select:not([multiple]) {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-position: right 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    padding: .5em;
    padding-right: 1.5em
}

#mySelect {
    border-radius: 0
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Based on [Arno Tenkink's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577471/arno-tenkink) suggestion in the comments, here is an example using a [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) instead of a [png](/questions/tagged/png) for the arrow icon.

```css
select:not([multiple]) {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-position: right 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="12" version="1"><path d="M4 8L0 4h8z"/></svg>');
    padding: .5em;
    padding-right: 1.5em
}

#mySelect {
    border-radius: 0
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can also use a SVG for this. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="14px" height="12px" viewBox="0 0 14 12" enable-background="new 0 0 14 12" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon points="3.862,7.931 0,4.069 7.725,4.069 "/></svg>` it saves same file space. It's also cacheable and easier to maintain. Copy this into a file and save as .svg and use it as a background.

Answer (score 215):

In addition to `border-radius: 0`, add `-webkit-appearance: none;`.

Comment: solution is right - but not being able to see why is this happening in dev tools is just straight wrong. thanks for solving the riddle man!

Comment: It works but not perfect, `-webkit-appearance: none;` will cause the select lack of arrow indicator on the right side.

Comment: @nightire It worked for me if you use `border: 0` and add an outline like: `outline: 1px inset black; outline-offset:-1px`. Will keep the arrows and you can fake the border with the outline.

Comment: @FilipePereira That not solved the problem in my case, but it added border outline with black color. it coming in mozilla not in chrome.

Comment: remove the line  `-webkit-appearance:none;` from css. or else expected output not come in Chrome Browser.

Comment: Not an ideal solution because this removes the select indicator arrows as well.

Comment: Yeah this is not really a solution because, like everyone has said, the selector arrow disappears.

Comment: @FilipePereira this works but outline-offset is not supported for IE

Comment: Don't forget IE! :) select::-ms-expand { display: none; }

Comment: For bootstrap@4 users, adding `custom-select` class will bring the arrows back.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and while user1732055's answer fixes the border, it removes the dropdown arrows.  I solved this by removing the border from the `select` element and creating a wrapper `span` which has a border.

html:

```
<span class="select-wrapper">
    <select class="form-control no-radius">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

css:

```
select.no-radius{
    border:none;
}    
.select-wrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrqh0drd/6/

Comment: This works only if the select has white background. Otherwise there will be a radius if another color is used.

Comment: Hi @MichalCh, good catch!  One way to get around this would be to set the background-color of the wrapper to the same value as the select element.  Here's a modified version on jsfiddle to demonstrate: [https://jsfiddle.net/Lrqh0drd/75/](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrqh0drd/75/)

Comment: This is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-webkit-border-radius: 0;`. Like this:-

```
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 1px solid grey;
outline-offset: -1px;
```

This will give square corners as well as dropdown arrows. Using `-webkit-appearance: none;` is not recommended as it will turn off all the styling done by Chrome.

Comment: but this has a problem too; it doesn't clear the outline border radius when focused.

Comment: @elquimista you can just use `outline: none;` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SVG from @ArnoTenkink as an data url combined with the accepted answer, this gives us the perfect solution for retina displays.

```
select.form-control:not([multiple]) {
    border-radius: 0;
    appearance: none;
    background-position: right 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%20%3C%21DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-//W3C//DTD%20SVG%201.1//EN%22%20%22http%3A//www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd%22%3E%20%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2212px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2012%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2014%2012%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%20%3Cpolygon%20points%3D%223.862%2C7.931%200%2C4.069%207.725%2C4.069%20%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E);
    padding: .5em;
    padding-right: 1.5em
}
```

Answer (score -5):

the class is called:

```
.form-control { border-radius: 0; }
```

be sure to insert the override after including bootstraps css.

If you ONLY want to remove the radius on select form-controls use

```
select.form-control { ... }
```

instead

EDIT: works for me on chrome, firefox, opera, and safari, IE9+ (all running on linux/safari & IE on playonlinux)

Comment: I specifically showed in the question how I changed the border-radius on form control and it didn't work..., which is what prompted me to ask the question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ut4y9/3/
here is a working fiddle. if it's still not working on your machine, could you please specify the browser you are using? I cannot reproduce your problem. sorry

Comment: Weird. I'm using the latest version of Chrome. Obviously it's something machine specific since you're both seeing it changed. Edit your answer so I can change my downvote :)

Comment: I've got the same issue. Despite my overriding the border-radius it still shows. Driving me nuts.

Comment: This is still the case with the most recent Bootstrap 3