# How to remove the border radius from select box components in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap v3.3.1 (the regular directory) and I can't success to remove the border radius from the select box components (in chrome).

This question **is not duplicated** because:

- **I already tried to change the bootstrap border-radius variables**
- **I already tried to add "(-webkit/-ms)border-radius: 0(px) !important" to the css**
- **I don't want the to add "-webkit-appearance: none;" to the css because I want the arrows of the select-component**

Comment: like I said in the bold section, the solutions from other questions didn't work for me

Comment: Yes I've realized that after, sorry, removed my previous comment. BTW, there was a solution for the arrow as a comment of that answer, can't it work for you? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210132/remove-border-radius-from-select-tag-in-bootstrap-3#comment42091112_24766039)

Comment: I tried and it's also a terrible solution

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this and it works for me

add form-control class in your select tag

and add this css

```
.form-control{
border-radius:0px;
}
```