# Compute style is not applied

Tags: css, google-chrome, less, google-developer-tools

I am adding some style to a webpage, but I am having a problem, I added a rule, and chrome developer tools say that is computed, but it is not applied. What this mean?

[image: Google developer tool]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is *always* the case, but I think this generally means that its been overridden by another rule with a higher degree of specificity.

CSS rules are graded in terms of how **specific** they are to an element, and when rules clash, then the *most specific* will be given precedence.
You can address this by adding a class directly to the element, or by making your rule stricter (more specific).

Comment: Mmmm I don't think that this could be the problem, I just added style="border-radius=0px !important" directly in the element, and the same happend. Google chrome dev show that the better rule is element.style but it stills giving the same style.

Comment: what happens if you set style="border-bottom-left-radius=0px !important" ?

Comment: If the property is being modified by a CSS with `animation` property, it can override the `!important` declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, if I add `border-bottom-left-radius=0px !important` the same happend, and I don't have css with animations, but I found the solution adding `-webkit-appearance: none` as says in this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210132/remove-border-radius-from-select-tag-in-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved the problem adding `-webkit-appearance: none`. Apparently google dev tools don't show webkit appearance but apply that.