# How to remove rounded corners of select box in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have written this code for creating a select box in bootstrap but the corners are coming rounded which i want to remove. How to do so? I tried a lot but could not find any solution for this. Please help me.

Here is the link of jsfiddle.net also

https://jsfiddle.net/ankitshri774/2redLfnc/7/

```css
body {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

label {
  float: left;
}

#main_container {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 13px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 13px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.select-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Master Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="masterpage1.css">


  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>



  <div id="main_container">

    <form>


      <div id="partymaster">
        <h3>Party Master</h3>
        <hr/>
      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category
                        <span style="color:red">*</span>
                    </label>
            <span class="select-wrapper"><select name="category" class="form-control no-radius">
                <option>A</option>      
                </select>
</span>
          </div>


        </div>


      </div>


    </form>


  </div>
</body>




</html>
```

Comment: `select.form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210132/remove-border-radius-from-select-tag-in-bootstrap-3

Comment: Which version of bootstrap you are using ? Your code shows version 3.3.7 but you have added bootstrap-4 tag on this question

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to your `CSS` file:

```
.no-radius{
    border-radius:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: There's a [`.rounded-0`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/#border-radius) utility class in BS4

Comment: Thanks for the information, fen1x. Here Ankit has already created a class 'no-radius', so I extend the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use code below(set `!important` to prevent override)

**The `border-radius` is `4px` because you set to select `form-control` class and it is bootstrap definition by default**

```
.no-radius{
  border-radius: unset!important;
}
```

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/2redLfnc/29/

```css
body{
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
       
    }
    
    
        label{
            float: left;
        }
        
        #main_container{
            background-color: white;
            margin-left: 10px;
            padding-left:13px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            padding-right:13px;
            padding-top: 13px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
        #container
        {
            background-color: aqua;
        }
    
       


       .select-wrapper{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 0px;
    }

.no-radius{
  border-radius: unset!important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    
<head>
<title>Master Page</title>                  
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="masterpage1.css">


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    

    <body >

            

            <div id="main_container">

    <form>
    
   
   <div id="partymaster">
       <h3>Party Master</h3>
       <hr/>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
      
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Category
                        <span style="color:red">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <span class="select-wrapper"><select name="category" class="form-control no-radius">
                <option>A</option>      
                </select>
</span>
                </div>
           
            
</div>


</div>


</form>


</div>
</body>




    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `form-control`-class sets a radius of 4px. So you can't overwrite it with a different class on the same element (at least I would not know how to that).
So as a quick fix, I have defined a different class `form-control-without-radius`and am using that in my [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93kc0puj/2/).

```
.form-control-without-radius {
  display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 34px;
padding: 6px 12px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #555;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

However, this is a fundamental change of the entire layout, and I guess it would collide with many other UI-Components. So you may have to build your own custom Bootstrap. Some people find it easy to do with [sass](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#file-structure), I had more fun using the [Bootstrap Theme Builder](https://bootstrap.build/app/v4.1.1/). And there are others as well. If you're not familiar enough with BT, this may sound like a scary idea - but my experience doing so has been only positive, so I'd go for it ;-)

**Update**: I saw the `unset !important`-idea in other posts, neat idea! That make the whole thing simpler, of course. Have updated [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vajf9xmy/) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `rounded-0` but in `Bootstrap-4` only.

```css
body {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

label {
  float: left;
}

#main_container {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 13px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 13px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.select-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="main_container">
  <form>
    <div id="partymaster">
      <h3>Party Master</h3>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Category
            <span style="color:red">*</span>
          </label>
          <span class="select-wrapper">
            <select name="category" class="form-control rounded-0">
              <option>A</option>      
            </select>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: On Firefox it's OK. But it still doesn't look right on Chrome.