# Dropdown list arrow customstyle

Tags: asp.net, css, html, html-select, dropdownbox

[image: Countrydropdown]

Is it possible to customize the arrow background  color of the dropdown using css/css3.

When the border color is default only black arrow seems to be visible.

on apply of  border color arrow appears as shown in image

Not interested to open/close div accordingly. looking for some styling to achieve.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the answer is no. I use jQuery plugins to style dropdowns. Take a look at [Chosenjs](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Word of warning, it's still a pain to do, even with Chosen.

Comment: You may want to start your edit from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185762/how-to-customized-select-element-through-css/10190884#10190884

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is no.  The browsers do not let you change the appearance of those kind of elements, like checkboxes, radio buttons, dropdowns, etc.

However, there are jQuery plugins out there that let you fake it thinking what you see is an authentic dropdown, but in reality it's something else, like an unordered list with a container div that resizes and contracts when you click on it.