# how to add customize select country dropdown arrow in twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please can any one help me, I want to add and customize select arrow in country select dropdown like this arrow image.

I have not enough reputation for posting image with this question so I have put this only image of problem here http://taslimk.tk/arrowproblem.html

Answer (score 0):

if you look here:

[How to customized select element through css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185762/how-to-customized-select-element-through-css/10190884#10190884)

it seems to be what you need, except the actual arrow doesn't work. not sure if that helps.

Comment: please help me about this matter