# Style mismatch in mozilla

Tags: css, firefox

[image: this is select box in chrome][image: this is select box in mozilla]i am having the following code to style the select box, it works perfectly in chrome but not in mozilla fire fox 27.0

```
 .select-box {
    line-height: inherit;
    width: 150px;
    height:150px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 1px 30px 0px 7px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background: #fdfffc;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfffc 0%, #f4f4f4 85%, #f4f4f4 95%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfffc),   color-stop(85%, #f4f4f4), color-stop(95%, #f4f4f4));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfffc 0%, #f4f4f4 85%, #f4f4f4 95%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfffc 0%, #f4f4f4 85%, #f4f4f4 95%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfffc 0%, #f4f4f4 85%, #f4f4f4 95%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdfffc 0%, #f4f4f4 85%, #f4f4f4 95%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fdfffc', endColorstr='#f4f4f4', GradientType=0);
    color: #dddddd;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fafafa;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mSL87/2/

Comment: please provide a fiddle that shows the issue, with the actual markup, and define what exactly  "not works" means

Comment: first read the question carefully, this has problem only with mozilla it works well in fiddle ok. kindly remove the minus vote

Comment: I didn't downvoted you. anyway you should provide a link showing how are you using that style, the markup to which is applied and describe what of those properties we should look at.

Comment: Perhaps provide some screen shots to demonstrate the issue. Saying "it does not work" is not enough information. Please be more specific.

Comment: I checked with my firefox (version 26) and it's working just fine, both in your jsfiddle and mine. Do you have some add-ons in your browser that might override some styles?

Comment: i added the images which shows the difference and my OS is ubuntu 13.04

Comment: I'm starting to suspect it's a browser/OS thing. The chrome in my windows OS is displaying it differently than yours.

Comment: ok is there any possibilities to fix this?

Comment: I don't know of any way. You can check the suggested solution in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185762/how-to-customized-select-element-through-css

Answer (score 1):

Try it this css -  mozilla fire fox 28.0

[image]

```
.select-box {
line-height: inherit;
width: 150px;
height:150px;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 3px 2px 2px 7px; /*i have editing in right pading*/
border:1px solid #999;    /*i have edit border */
height: 30px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-top: 2px;
background: #fdfffc;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfffc 0%, #f4f4f4 85%, #f4f4f4 95%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfffc),   color-stop(85%, #f4f4f4), color-stop(95%, #f4f4f4));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfffc 0%, #f4f4f4 85%, #f4f4f4 95%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfffc 0%, #f4f4f4 85%, #f4f4f4 95%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfffc 0%, #f4f4f4 85%, #f4f4f4 95%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdfffc 0%, #f4f4f4 85%, #f4f4f4 95%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fdfffc', endColorstr='#f4f4f4', GradientType=0);
color: #dddddd;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fafafa;
}
```

Comment: now the arrow is get fixed in right side but the style is still missing

Comment: Look is like add this - padding: 3px 2px 2px 7px; -
border:1px solid #999;