# Styling a <select> dropdown

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to style a `<select>` dropdown to look something similar to this. As in I want the grey background on page load and then the blue-ish color when it is active.

Here is what I have gotten so far. The main thing I'm trying to figure out is the colored block with the arrow to the right of the element.

```css
select {
   background: url(media/icons/down_arrow.png) no-repeat 90% ;
   background-size: 15px 10px;
   height: 30px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100px;
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   border: 2px solid #777;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: #EEE;
   color: #000;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
select:active, select:focus, select:hover {
  border: 2px solid #55E;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option>1000</option>
<option>2000</option>
<option>3000</option>
<option>4000</option>
<option>5000</option>
</select>
```

P.S. the png is just a down arrow that is 15px x 10px

Comment: May be of some use to get things rolling: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: You can use [Pseudo Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customized select element through css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185762/how-to-customized-select-element-through-css)

Comment: @cale_b Sorta, but technically not a duplicate, as this is asking for help with applying a *specific* style look that is different from that question, which is asking for help with applying a *different specific style*.

Comment: @TylerH - I hear that and understand.  Do you think SO should contain answers for every possible specific style request for every possible html element?

Comment: @cale_b *Should*? No. *Can*? By the definition of the site's scope, yes. More relevant to this situation is the requirement that the answer(s) of a target question answer a duplicate question in order to be a valid dupe target. In this case, the answers on the target would not serve as answers to this question. I am assuming you were attracted to that question by the generic nature of the title (which I've since changed)... in the event such a broad question is asked and answered with broadly-applicable solutions, then both your target and this Q could ostensibly be closed as dupes of *it*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider gradient coloration

```css
select {
   background:
     /*to replace the arrow*/
     linear-gradient(to bottom right,#fff 48%,transparent 50%) right 7px top 50%/8px 10px,
     linear-gradient(to bottom left,#fff 48%,transparent 50%) right 15px top 50%/8px 10px,     
    /*  remove the above gradient and uncomment the below to use your arrow
        url(media/icons/down_arrow.png) right 5px top 50%/15px 10px,
    */   
    var(--c,linear-gradient(#939393,#595959)) right/30px 100%,
    linear-gradient(#fffff9,#cfced5);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   font-size: 18px;
   padding:10px 40px 10px 10px;
   border: 2px solid #777;
   border-radius: 10px;
   color: #000;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
select:active, select:focus, select:hover {
  border: 2px solid #55E;
  /*Used a variable to avoid repeating all the background definition*/
  --c:linear-gradient(#6c81b7,#264091);
}
```

```html
<select>
<option>1000</option>
<option>2000</option>
<option>3000</option>
<option>4000</option>
<option>5000</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I needed, didn't realize you could add multiple statements to the background